# Angular2, is there a way for a child to have a reference to it's parent. ES6

Tags: angularjs, angular, ecmascript-6

In a child component, is there a way to get a reference to the parent component?

I would like to call a method when something happens to the child.

Event emitters are not so great in this case because the child and the parent don't explicitly contain each other in the templates. 
 Both use `<ng-content></ng-content>` and let the user define what he wants in the templates. But I would like the child component to be able to let it's parent know when something happened.

Detail: I am trying to do this in ES6.

Comment: Please explain *don't explicitly contain each other in the templates*, are you refering to an `router-outlet`?

Comment: I mean that the templates only define `<ng-content></ng-content>` and almost nothing more, the components mostly add js and css wrapping on whatever the user wants to put inside those components.

if <ng-content></ng-content> is considered to be an outlet content, then yes.

Comment: Would it make sense for them to use the same service?

Comment: I am hesitating on making them use the same service since the parent references the children to arrange them (with ContentChildren) in the view and to forward some events to the currently active element. I guess a possible solution would be to have the service do this instead and also handle calls from children to parent when a child is directly interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use Subject  (from RxJS)  with Parent subscribing to it and Child emitting the event  (via next () method) when required.
The Subject instance can be moved around via Dependency Injection. 
I hope this helps

Comment: For more details on this and an example: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service